# Can I Make A Background Service That runs at certain intervals of time even after closing the Application

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am Referring this Application  https://github.com/hzitoun/android-camera2-secret-picture-taker. 
In this Application there are two classes(APictureCapturingService.java & PictureCapturingServiceImpl.java) that takes pictures without preview can these two classes be converted to Background Service that runs always never dies.

Is this possible to have camera capturing process as a background service if yes how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are taking picture in your activity but i can guide you to run your app in background even your close your app and you can able to run your camera code in every second..

```
public class SampleService extends Service {

public SampleService() {
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent inten, int flags, int startId) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                        // Make use your method here..

                }
            });
        }
    }, 5000, 2000);

    return super.onStartCommand(inten, flags, startId);
}



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}}
```

And you need to start the service form activity..

```
startService(new Intent(this, SampleService.class));
```

I have used this for monitoring the foreground app it will work..